# Dart is too fast

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying to understand why this code print "check" twice...

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<Map> ft_get_data() {
  File data;

  data = new File("data.json");
  return data.exists().then((value) {
    if (!value) {
      print("Data does no exist...\nCreating file...");
      data.createSync();
      print("Filling it...");
      data.openWrite().write('{"index":{"content":"Helllo"}}');
      print("Operation finish");
    }
  }).then((_) => data.readAsString()).then((content) => JSON.decode(content)
      ).catchError((e) => new Map());
}

void main() {
  Map params;
  String name;
  num check = 0;

  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080).then((server) {
    print("Server is lauching... $server");
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED;
      request.response.headers.contentType = new ContentType('text', 'htm    l');
      params = request.uri.queryParameters; // http://127.0.0.1:8080/?name=tristan
      ft_get_data().then((data_map) {
        name = data_map['index']['content'];
        print('check: $check');
        if (data_map.isNotEmpty) request.response.write(name); else
            request.response.write('Booh');
        check++;
      }).whenComplete(request.response.close);
    });
  }).catchError((error) {
    print("An error : $error.");
  });
}
```

Is it too fast ? Or there exist some method to make a pause ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it prints `0`.

What client are you using to access the server?

Comment: Chrome, Safari and I use IntelliJ EDI

Comment: I guess this is because browsers try to get the `favicon.ico` file in an automatic second request. You can print the request to show what the client is actually requesting `print(request.requestedUri);`.

Comment: You right ! http://127.0.0.1:8080/?name=Hugo and http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico is send... Great, so how I can catch them one by one ?

Comment: That are two totally different requests, you have nothing to do. It is possible that your server starts processing the second request before the first is finished but that is usually no problem (it may annoy when you debug though). You can check if `request.requestedUri` ends with `favicon.ico` and just call `request.response.close` and return.

Comment: I did "(request.uri.path != "/")" request.response.close(); return ;